# Why did this question about upgrading ML to Mavericks get closed a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Why did [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111897/upgrade-to-mavericks-from-mountain-lion-offline-with-dmg-file) get marked as duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-mavericks-install-usb-flash-drive) and closed?

I think the scenarios are opposites: I want to upgrade without using an external drive and the supposed question I duplicated is about creating USB drive to upgrade.

My problem is, I have an OS X Mavericks dmg file. I have tried OS X install app but, after agreeing to software licence agreement, when I click to install, nothing happens.

I want to know if it's possible to upgrade Mountain Lion to Mavericks from the installer dmg file without using an external drive -- as it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It was closed because someone thought the linked question provided an answer for yours. Since that does not answer your question, edit your question to make it clearer that what you are looking for is not that. That said, I suspect you might be asking the wrong question. Your question does not make clear enough in the body of the question that your dmg is not from the App Store directly; have you verified the checksum of your dmg file?

Comment: ok thanks, i understand what you meant.. i may not have expressed my question clearly as it could be  but the language used in the question is also not that much bad that it's sentiment will be just opposite..